# Are currently 280 dependencies required to use angular2?

Tags: angular, dependencies, licensing

I am doing the ng2 getting started tutorial, described [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html):  that currently consist only of a default package.json on which I do a `npm install`

The package.json references only two dev dependencies, all others are first or second level dependencies required for angular.

Now my node_modules has a total count of 280 packages with 10.648 files and 986 directories.

I might be late to the game, but can I condense or deploy the total minimum set of those deps when deploying? And I don't mean minification.

Is everybody else simply dumping ~11k of additional files to a web server to display some 6 file large angular app? Also casually ignoring about 280 licenses?

What's about all those licences? How can I actually be sure that I don't violate any licence terms without checking each of those 280 packages? There are scenarios where in a corporate environment licence validation is absolutely crucial to be able to use something.

I mean there is a sub package, whose copyright is held by Walmart, called `hoek`

This is not a rant, I **do** want to use angular but I also don't want to be held liable for possible licence violations by pushing all those node modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of those packages come from the development dependencies. When you deploy on an actual server you want to run `npm install --production` and then you'll see the list of packages installed is very much shorter:

```
PS C:\play\angular-quickstart> npm install --dry-run --production
angular-quickstart@1.0.0 C:\play\angular-quickstart
+-- @angular/common@2.3.1
+-- @angular/compiler@2.3.1
+-- @angular/core@2.3.1
+-- @angular/forms@2.3.1
+-- @angular/http@2.3.1
+-- @angular/platform-browser@2.3.1
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.3.1
+-- @angular/router@3.3.1
+-- @angular/upgrade@2.3.1
+-- angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17
+-- core-js@2.4.1
+-- reflect-metadata@0.1.8
+-- rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
| `-- symbol-observable@1.0.4
`-- zone.js@0.7.3

npm WARN angular-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

If you review the equivalent output for the default `npm install` command you'll see that almost all of the packages are listed as dependencies of `lite-server` which is the web server you use for testing. In production you'll want to be using a real web server so you don't need any of those packages.

Comment: Oh boy, 273 dependencies come from the 2 dev ones, albeit I understand that the lite server may require a lot of them.